# Display Image from the path stored in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have uploaded the image into the folder and stored the path into the MySQL Database. The path has been stored and the image has been inserted into the folder successfully. But my problem is when i display the image from the path which is stored in db. It is not displaying. When i echo the image path, it displays the image path. I checked my browser settings, it's all ok. Here is my code. Please anybody help.

```
$up=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'],dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/htdocs/upload/image/'.$name);
$path = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/htdocs/upload/image/';
$location = $path . $_FILES['profile']['name'];
$ins=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into image (url) values ('$location')");
echo 'image uploaded and stored';
echo "$location"; //It displays D:/xampp/htdocs/upload/image/Chrysanthemum.jpg
echo '<img width="250" height="250" src= "'.$location.'"/>';//It doesn't display anything.
```

Comment: use relative path. just use `upload/image/` for path.

Comment: only store the `/uploads/image` in your database or just image name

Comment: You're passing image absolute path. Try with `upload/image/Chrysanthemum.jpg` instead

Comment: You are passing physical path to image. Either path absolute URL of image or relative path with document root. Images get displayed with `http://`, not with `D:/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this:**

Try to use `relative path` not `absolute path`. The relative path helps you to run the script from any server, any directory.

```
$path = 'upload/image/';
$location = $path . $_FILES['profile']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'], $location);

$ins = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into image (url) values ('$location')");
echo 'image uploaded and stored';
echo '<img width="250" height="250" src= "'.$location.'"/>';
```

> Note: you need to have a folder name `upload/image` in the same
>   directory from where the script run. As your requirement, you want to show image from mysql, but did't do it, for that you need to query the table again.

Comment: @Jebil, so mark this as your answer so that other people get helped from this.

Answer (score 0):

hey you can use below code to get path of uploaded image in dir this code will show your image

```
$location ='/upload/image/'. $_FILES['profile']['name']; // write your project dir name before upload if "upload is not your project dir"

$ins=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into image (url) values ('$location')");
echo 'image uploaded and stored';

echo '<img width="250" height="250" src= "'.$location.'"/>';//It doesn't display anything.
```