# i need to put an image from a database to a card

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

The problem si that the image i want to show an image from a database where an user uploads an image and can been shown to a card with some info lik its name and price but when i tried to do it an icon appears like a paper with green here is my code

```
 <?php
                   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
$stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
?>

<?php
while ($campo = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>

<div class="col-4">
    <div class="card">
       <img src="data:imagen/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode( $imagen); ?>" />
       <h2><?php echo $campo['firstname']; ?></h2>
       <h4>Talla <?php echo $campo['talla'];?></h4>
       <h4>$<?php echo $campo['precio'];?></h4>
       
   </div>
 </div>
 <br>
 <?php
}

?>
```

the user uploads an image with a crud in ajax i dont know if anyone want to see that code to

i tried almost anything and nothing seems to work it just look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjaUU.png)

Comment: Please show us where $imagen is set.and also describe what debugging you have done. For example have you checked all the php variables are set correctly e.g. using var_dump?

Comment: Hi Valente, I understand that you want to show image from database in web page directly. Though it's possible, I strongly suggest you upload the image in some folder and save that path in database. Then, you can just link that image path in **img src**  variable. This way, it's hassle free and works for all images including very massive sized ones without any issues. This is how most systems work instead of showing from DB directly as base64 encoded. It's a good reference for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995820/display-image-from-the-path-stored-in-mysql

Comment: Also you can store only unique image name in the DB. and store the path as a constant . This will reduce the storage of DB.

Comment: There's a typo in the mime type `data:imagen/jpeg;` should be `data:image/jpeg;`

Comment: thank you so much with your answers but i resolved the problem it seems that a code i put was wrong and i just edit out but thanks a lot i never expected to people answer this quickly

Answer (score 1):

What I can see is you have set a while loop on $campo and then called individually in an loop. for image you can try href="{{ $campo['$imagen'] }}" though I would suggest to use foreach loop for this purpose.

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
<img src="{{ $details['image'] }}" width="100" height="100" class="img-responsive"/>
</div>
```